# How can I launch an async prompt to confirm updating SelectedItem in a WPF ListBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, asynchronous, listbox

I have a ListBox bound to an `ObservableCollection` of objects. Selecting object loads it into the UI for editing and saving.

I would like that when selecting a new object in the ListBox that there is a prompt if there is unsaved changes UI so a check needs to occur when the ListBox selection changes and a prompt appears to confirm the change - if the change is confirmed then it happens as normal otherwise the change is prevented/undone.

The prompt code is an `async` method that returns a Task and so it cannot occur in a setter - it can occur in an event though which I have had limited success with.

It seems we only have access to `SelectionChanged` event. I can prompt here but when reverting the `SelectionChanged` event is fired again to result in an infinite loop.

Given that this is probably quite a common pattern - what is the best practice way to handle this?

Comment: Why cant you do it inside the setter?

Comment: @AmitRaz Async cannot be used inside a setter

Comment: You can place it in a method and call it from your setter

Comment: @AmitRaz How? As far as I can tell, we get a `Task` back in most circumstances but this needs to be `await`ed. We can use `.Result` to resolve the `Task` in a non-async method but this blocks the UI thread in this case and so the prompt is never shown ...

Answer (score 1):

Add a method that calls your *prompt code* as you call it and then returns the value. After that, you can simply call that method from the setter of the property that is data bound to the `SelectedItem` property:

```
public YourDataType CurrentItem
{
    get { return currentItem; }
    set
    {
        if (isChangeConfirmed)
        {
            isChangeConfirmed = false;
            currentItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
        else GetIsChangeConfirmed(value);
    }
}

public async void GetIsChangeConfirmed(object value)
{
    isChangeConfirmed = await YourAsyncPromptMethod();
    if (isChangeConfirmed) CurrentItem = value;
}

private bool isChangeConfirmed = false;
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Actually, as you correctly pointed out, there are some restrictions over the use of `async` methods. To get around that, you can set the confirmation value to a variable that you check inside the setter as shown above, instead of returning it from the method.

Comment: Hmm, I get "The return type of an async method can only be Task, Task<T> or a bool"

Comment: Do: 
bool res = await YourAsyncPromptMethod(); 
return res;

Comment: Thanks @AmitRaz, but that would not get rid of the error that Brendan mentioned.

Comment: Why would it cause an error? he is not awaiting inside the property but simply calling a method. I have done this many times.

Comment: For the same reason... because *The return type of an `async` method must be `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`*.

Comment: @Sheridan This method you propose goes into a loop if you decline the change. You can assign `CurrentItem` conditionally in the `GetIsChangeConfirmed` method but then the UI is not updated when thechange is declined. Also even if the logic is factored so that the `CurrentItem` is assigned back to the previous value, raising `PropertyChanged` does not update the UI for some reason.

Comment: I've updated the code again, so that changes are only made to the `currentItem` variable if your asynchronous method returns `true`.

Comment: @Sheridan, the UI goes out of synch in this case - if you decline the change and the property does not update, the ListBox UI still shows the the declined value as selected - in this case raising `PropertyChanged` does not 'refresh' the UI or binding. I have had some success with finding the index and setting `SelectedIndex` eplicitly on the `ListBox` instance but this brings UI code into my ViewModel which is far from ideal

Comment: Then just let the value change and then change it back if your method returns `false`... are you going to do any of this?

Comment: I have implemented the code now that does not update the ViewModel value if the prompt is declined. It also calls UI code and sets the `SelectedIndex` property on the ListBox to get the UI to match the ViewModel state. The async code is run in an `async void` method which  runs in 'fire-and'forget' kind of way and so might not be resilient to rapid updating of `CurrentItem`. It works in practice but it gives me the creeps ...